# how to draw circle with only its stroke

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, geometry

I just want to draw circle with stroke, the code below draws well but it fills the circle.

I do not want it filled. Please help me

```
    self.circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,20,20)];
    circleView.alpha = 0.5;
    self.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
    self.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
self.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

to

```
self.circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and for the border (Stroke) add

```
self.circleView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
self.circleView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

Comment: it is blank now, nothing appears on the screen

Comment: oh you have to set the borderWidth also: `self.circleView.layer.borderWidth = 2`

Comment: then this is the problem, i just want to fill inside of the circle with a number;
my code is
UILabel* circleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [circleLabel setText:@"1"];
        
        [circleView addSubview:circleLabel];

but it does not work

Comment: that's because your circleLabel has a frame (0,0,0,0). You need to use `[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:<yourRect>];` insted of `[[UILabel alloc] init];`